# How to find path to running application programatically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I'm developing a C# application that uses a SQLite database. In my project, I created a new folder called 'database'. In the database folder, I have a database called 'ldm'. I define my data source like this:

Data Source=/database/ldm;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;

When I run the code in VS2010, it runs fine. When I publish it, it can't find the database. Obviously, this has to be a path problem but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Thanks!
Anthony

Comment: Are you sure the database is in the published output? Check the Build Action for the database file via the Properties window.

Comment: _"When I publish it, it can't find the database."_ What program is giving that error (Visual Studio, during publishing, or your application when you run it) and what does it say exactly?

Comment: Dash: It looks like what you suggested was the problem. The Build Action was "none". As soon as I changed it to "Resource" things started working. Though now, even though I'm able to connect to my DB, for some reason, it's not finding the table. I KNOW it's there. Does SQLite require some kind of table prefix? If my table name is documents is there a special way to access it?

Comment: @CodeCaster It was being thrown by my application when I ran it. But it looks like my Build Action was causing the problem.

Comment: @Anthony what is _"not finding the table"_, please provide exact error messages. It's most probably a permissions issue.

Comment: @CodeCaster: It's an SQLiteException. It says "SQLite error: no such table: documents". Right now, I'm running this on Windows XP. Could it still be a perm issue?

Comment: @Anthony well it's either something with permissions, or with the path, as far as I can tell from searching for that error. :)

Comment: Thank you @CodeCaster. I'm digging into it now.

Comment: @Anthony try 'Content' for the build action, along with 'Copy Always'

Answer (score 2):

If it's winforms, you can use [`Application.ExecutablePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx).

Otherwise, you can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Answer (score 1):

What are you running on?

If it's asp.net you can MapPath

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx